# Android issues with AsyncTask and InputStream

Tags: android, android-asynctask, inputstream

I've been trying to figure this out on my own for quite a while.. by trial/error as well as research, but I just can't seem to get it figured out. I'm pretty bad with Async and network connections and stuch, so it might be something simple that I'm over looking. Anyway... I'll paste some relevant code samples and explanations.

Quick background of my problem. I'm working with the Rotten Tomatoes API for my app, and am using GSON for the parsing of their data. I was initially targeting 2.3, and this worked fine. Then I decided to have support for ICS, and of course ran into the "no network operation on the UI thread" - so I started to delve into AsyncTask.

Here is my InputStream method:

```
private InputStream retrieveStream(String url) {

    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);

    try {

        HttpResponse getResponse = client.execute(getRequest);
        final int statusCode = getResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(),
                    "Error " + statusCode + " for URL " + url);
            return null;
        }

        HttpEntity getResponseEntity = getResponse.getEntity();
        return getResponseEntity.getContent();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        getRequest.abort();
        Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error for URL " + url, e);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Which was working fine in my main activity, and now is giving me issues when trying to 'convert' it into AsyncTask. I've been calling it like this:

```
InputStream source = retrieveStream( url parameter );
```

Then I tried moving that method into my AsyncTask class, and calling it like this:

```
private PerformMovieSearch performSearch = new PerformMovieSearch(this);
InputStream source = performSearch.retrieveStream(movieQueryUrl);
```

But that doesn't cut it, still get the error about performing network actions on the UI. What I need to figure out is how to call 'retrieveStream' from the AsyncTask I guess. Currently that class looks like this:

```
package net.neonlotus.ucritic;

[imports]

public class PerformMovieSearch extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

private final Context context;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;


public PerformMovieSearch(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}


@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
    retrieveStream(urls[0]);

    return null;

}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    progressDialog= ProgressDialog.show(context, "Please Wait","Searching movies", true);

}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    progressDialog.dismiss();

    MyActivity.mListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public InputStream retrieveStream(String url) {

    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);

    try {
        HttpResponse getResponse = client.execute(getRequest);
        final int statusCode = getResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(),
                    "Error " + statusCode + " for URL " + url);
            return null;
        }

        HttpEntity getResponseEntity = getResponse.getEntity();
        return getResponseEntity.getContent();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        getRequest.abort();
        Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error for URL " + url, e);
    }

    return null;
}
```

}

The "doinbackground" is what needs to be changed... but I can't seem to find a straight way to get that working properly. I was executing using

```
new PerformMovieSearch(this).execute(movieQueryUrl);
```

I know that is a lot of stuff, potentially confusing... but if anybody knows how to essentially do the retrieveStream method asynchronously, that would be great. Like I said, Ive tried many things, did plenty of research, just could not come up with anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the point is, you didn't understand how asynctask works!

You MUST read the guide Processes and Threads: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

But ok, let me try help you.

On doInBackground you are correctly calling the method retrieveStream, but you are doing nothing with the stream. So, you have to process the stream and then, return it. As you said you are expecting an JSON, I'm assuming you will receive a String, so the code of your retrieveStream should like this:

```
public String retrieveStream(String url) {

    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);

    try {
        HttpResponse getResponse = client.execute(getRequest);
        final int statusCode = getResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(),
                    "Error " + statusCode + " for URL " + url);
            return null;
        }

        HttpEntity getResponseEntity = getResponse.getEntity();
        String jsonString = EntityUtils.toString(getResponseEntity);
        return jsonString;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        getRequest.abort();
        Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error for URL " + url, e);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Look that I changed the return type to String. And maybe, you should change the name to retrieveMoviesJSON or something like this.

And you should change your AsyncTask to something like this:

```
class PerformMovieSearch AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<Movie>>() {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                progressDialog= ProgressDialog.show(context, "Please Wait","Searching movies", true);
            }

            @Override
            protected ArrayList<Movie> doInBackground(String... params) {
                String moviesJson = retrieveStream[params[0]];
                JSONObject moviesJson = new JSONObject(moviesJson);
                ArrayList<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<Movie>();
                /*
                 * Do your code to process the JSON and create an ArrayList of films.
                 * It's just a suggestion how to store the data.
                 */
                return movies;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Movie> result) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                //create a method to set an ArrayList in your adapter and set it here.
                MyActivity.mListAdapter.setMovies(result);
                MyActivity.mListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
```

And you can call as the same way you were doing.

Is it clear? Need more explanation?

[]s
Neto

Answer (score 0):

What sort of behavior are you seeing that is unexpected.  From scanning your code, it looks like it probably compiles and runs but I would guess that your ListAdapter never gets updated with fresh data (i.e. you're probably trying to display the results in a ListView or GridView but nothing is showing up).  Is that correct? Or are you still getting the Network on Main Thread error?

You are retrieving data using your HTTP Client and then not doing anything with it.  One way you could solve it is to structure your code such that:
1) Your class that extends AsyncTask has a constructor that takes a ListAdapter object
2) Your main Activity would create an instance of the AsyncTask and pass in a reference to its ListAdapter object
3) Your doInBackground method would handle all the network activity and return the result (the data you pulled from the web service) so that it gets passed down to the onPostExecute method
4) In onPostExecute, you will have the data that was returned from doInBackground, and you'll have the ListAdapter that was provided in the constructor, so parse the data, populate the ListAdapter, and invalidate it so that the list gets redrawn.

Keep in mind that AsyncTask lets you interact with the UI thread in both the onPreExecute and onPostExecute methods, so those are the only places that you can draw to the screen (i.e. populating the adapter and invalidating it so that it will redraw)

Comment: I was just running into the network actions on the main thread issue. I do have to research more about Async and related topics. But I'll take these points into consideration. Thanks!