# Implementation of Async Task

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to implement **Async Task** in this class but the thing is that I am calling `getInputStream` function in my program which is returning a value and I am not sure Where to put it. Where should I define `getInputStream` in my async task? 
I am getting the below exception

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity      com.sparkplug.xxxx}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Below is my main class:

```
public class abcreaderextends ListActivity {

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    parsing p=new parsing();

        @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_awsreader);
        ((PullToRefreshListView) getListView())
                .setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener() {
                    public void onRefresh() {
                        // Do work to refresh the list here.
                        new GetDataTask().execute();
                    }
                });
        InputStreamOperation in= new InputStreamOperation();

        in.execute();

        //p.parse();

        for (int i = 0; i < p.headlines.size(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put("title", p.headlines.get(i));
            map.put("dcdate", p.lstDate.get(i));
            map.put("description", p.description.get(i));
            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            menuItems.add(map);
        }

                ListAdapter rssFeedSection = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[] { "title", "dcdate",
                        "description" }, new int[] { R.id.name, R.id.date1,
                        R.id.desc });
        setListAdapter(rssFeedSection);
    }

    class GetDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String[]> {
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
            // **menuItems.addFirst("Added after refresh...");
            // Call onRefreshComplete when the list has been refreshed.
            ((PullToRefreshListView) getListView()).onRefreshComplete();
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse((String) p.links.get(position));
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

This is my parsing class:
    public class parsing {
        List headlines;
        List links;
        List description;
        List lstDate;
        List newDate;
        //String a,b,c,d;
        public InputStream getInputStream(URL url) {
            try {
                return url.openConnection().getInputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return null;
            }
        }

```
    public HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> parse() {

        // Initializing instance variables
        headlines = new ArrayList<String>();
        links = new ArrayList<String>();
        description = new ArrayList<String>();
        lstDate = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            URL url = new URL(
                    "http://feeds.feedburner.com/xxxx");
            XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
            XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
            // We will get the XML from an input stream
            xpp.setInput(getInputStream(url), "UTF_8");
            int i = 0;
            boolean insideItem = false;
            // Returns the type of current event: START_TAG, END_TAG, etc..
            int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
            int k = 0;
            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                i++;
                // Log.i("Tag : ",xpp.getName().toString());
                // Log.i("Text : ",xpp.nextText().toString());
                if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                    Log.i("Tag : ", xpp.getName().toString());
                    // Log.i("Text : ",xpp.nextText().toString());
                    if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                        insideItem = true;
                    } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
                        if (insideItem) {
                            String var = xpp.nextText().toString();
                            headlines.add(var); // extract the description of
                                                // article
                            Log.i("Title : ", var);
                            // Log.i("Count : ",i+"");
                        }
                    } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("description")) {
                        if (insideItem) {
                            String desc = xpp.nextText().toString();
                            description.add(desc); // extract the description of
                                                    // article
                            Log.i("Desc : ", desc);
                        }
                    } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("dc:date")) {
                        if (insideItem) {
                            String strDate = xpp.nextText().toString();

                            System.out.println("rahul"+strDate.substring(0,10));
                            //lstDate = Arrays.asList(arr[k].substring(0,10));
                            lstDate.add(strDate.substring(0,10));
                            System.out.println("lstDate"+lstDate);
                            k = k+1;
                            Log.i("Date : ", strDate);
                        }
                    } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("link")) {
                        if (insideItem)
                            links.add(xpp.nextText()); // extract the link of
                                                        // article
                    }
                } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG
                        && xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                    insideItem = false;
                }
                eventType = xpp.next(); // move to next element
            }// While end
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> alllists = 
                                        new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
        alllists.put("headlines",(ArrayList<String>) headlines);
        alllists.put("links",(ArrayList<String>) links);
        alllists.put("description",(ArrayList<String>) description);
        alllists.put("lstDate",(ArrayList<String>) lstDate);

        return alllists;
        }
}
```

and this one is my InputStreamOperation class:
    public class InputStreamOperation extends AsyncTask>> {

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
// show progress bar here(have not used any progress bar)
}

@Override
protected HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> 
                           doInBackground(Void... params) {

//call parse() method here
parsing parsingobj=new parsing();
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> alllists=parsingobj.parse();

return alllists;  //<<< retun final result from here

}      

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> result) {  
// update UI here            
}

}
```

Comment: You really need to read this book. http://www.amazon.com/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882

Comment: @Rahul plz check out my answer no need to make more changes in current code just call parse() inside AsyncTask and change return type of parse() to HashMap to return more then one ArrayList to doInBackground

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need to call `getInputStream` inside `doInBackground` method of AsyncTask as:

First Change parse method return type to `HashMap<String, String>` as :

```
public HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> parse() {

 ///your code here...

HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> alllists = 
                                new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
alllists.put("headlines",headlines);
alllists.put("links",links);
alllists.put("description",description);
alllists.put("lstDate",lstDate);

return alllists;
}
```

and Create AsyncTask class as :

```
private class InputStreamOperation extends 
                    AsyncTask<String, Void, HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>> {

      @Override
      protected void onPreExecute() {
        // show progress bar here
      }

      @Override
      protected HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> 
                                               doInBackground(String... params) {

           //call parse() method here
          parsing parsingobj=new parsing();
          HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> alllists=parsingobj.parse();

          return alllists;  //<<< retun final result from here

      }      

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> result) {  
              // update UI here            
      }


}
```

Comment: I am getting the below exception
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity  
              ComponentInfo{com.sparkplug.awsreader/com.sparkplug.awsreader.AWSreader}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)

Comment: :I have updated my question with the class files and the log. Can I have multilevel functions in Async task?

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I am ubable to access the elements of the `parsing class` in my `Activity class` as eclipse is not recognizing them. Any suggestions?

Comment: @RahulSingh : why you are accessing elements of the parsing class in Activity try to access it inside onPostExecute of Async task . and also post your latest code because you are not doing same as suggested by me

Comment: Sorry mate, it is still not working. I mean everything is fine now but I guess some issues with the `onPostExecute` in the `InputStreamOperation` class. It returns `result` but nothing is displayed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23201/discussion-between-rahul-singh-and--k)

Answer (score 1):

Try like this..

```
class Search AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<Movie>>() {

                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    progressDialog= ProgressDialog.show(context, "Please Wait","Searching movies", true);
                }

                @Override
                protected ArrayList<Movie> doInBackground(String... params) {
                    String moviesJson = retrieveStream[params[0]];
                    JSONObject moviesJson = new JSONObject(moviesJson);
                    ArrayList<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<Movie>();
                    /*
                     * Do your code to process the JSON and create an ArrayList of films.
                     * It's just a suggestion how to store the data.
                     */
                    return movies;
                }

                protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Movie> result) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    //create a method to set an ArrayList in your adapter and set it here.
                    sampleActivity.mListAdapter.setMovies(result);
                    sampleActivity.mListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
```

For more information..

[Android issues with AsyncTask and InputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12849014/android-issues-with-asynctask-and-inputstream)

Answer (score 0):

It should be written in the doInBackground()  method.

Due to formatting problems i am not able to upload the exact code

1 create a class extending asyncTask with 
2 Write getInputStream in doInBackground
3 Call the asynctask to get InputStream